# how to show progress bar status by percentage

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am using progress dialog for android 2.3.3. Progress dialog's status is showing with the format as "60% 60/100" but I want to display only percentage not "60/100". How can I do it? please help.

Answer (score 20):

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgressNumberFormat%28java.lang.String%29), you should call `setProgressNumberFormat (null)` on your `ProgressDialog` instance to get this behavior

Comment: the method that you have mentioned is applicable for api level 11. mine is 10

Comment: My bad :( I've dig into source code and find out that there is no "normal" way to do it in api 10. I just can propose as workaround to get full ProgessDialog code from Android 4.0.1 and use it instead of built-in version. Maybe, it'll be some mess with android "internal" resources, but it is also available as sources to reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Please visit [this](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html) link.

Also It's explained in full in ApiDemos inside the SDK. The example that you want is named: ProgressBar3.java and can be found in \ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view\

Also, if you want to remove the borders of the dialog so that only the progress bar appears you can define the dialog itself as a transparent view/overlay (it's explained in the examples as well).