# Android Display Progress Dialog while doing a background task

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I am building an android app which will download some data and display it to the user. Now I need to show a circular progress bar until the data is downloaded. The download will begin on a button click. How can I achieve this? Sample code would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes you can do that with Progressbar widget. And thread in your class.

Comment: can u show me some sample code.?

Comment: Google helps a looooottttttt. hundreds of tutorials. Search "ProgressDialog" for instance.

Comment: Refer to some examples that are available on net easily. 

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043683/how-to-show-progress-bar-status-by-percentage, http://androidsamplecodes4u.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-progress-bar-with-primary-and.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to execute your download and [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) instance to show a circular progress.

There are many resources you can find which describe exactly how to use the combination to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Check Android AsyncTask class for what you want to achieve.

Basically you start showing a ProgressDialog in the onPreExecute of AsyncTask and dismiss it in onPostExecute when your background job is done.

Check these also.

[android how to work with asynctasks progressdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450275/android-how-to-work-with-asynctasks-progressdialog)

http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/11/for-my-app-moustachify-everything-i-was.html

http://javatech.org/2011/02/discovering-android-opening-a-progress-dialog-with-asynctask/