# How to download the series of Images from Server

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-async-http

I have my own Server and I want to download the images one by one automatically. 
Right now what I have tried is downloading and saving the image on the device and that is working 100 percent perfectly. But that is working for single image here is the good [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875114/android-save-image-from-url-onto-sd-card) on it.  But It is working but downloading only one image or you can say one image for one link .

The Idea came into my mind and that is to make the string array of the Url and then apply the for loop and then it would download and execute that much Asynctask.

But this is not a good practice, as it would launch too many async task.

**What I want**

1. I want that if I have 10 Url , then it should download images from
   first url to last url but one by one , I mean when First Image has
   been downloaded then it should start second image after saving the
   first Image on device.
2. It should Show Progress bar progress collectively for all images. and should Update the progress let say there are 10 images then it should show 10 percent completed when first images has been successfully downloaded and it should show 20 percent if 2 images has been downloaded.

Please give me source code or anything which can Help me. Thanks.

Comment: You have to make logic on server side. Android is just a client application. it only does download, the server has to decide how much amount of files that has to send for client side application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you try this for loop inside the aysncTask, as this wont create multiple aysncTask objects, less memory use.

```
 public class httpDownloadImages extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        Bitmap myBitmap[]=new Bitmap[10];
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showProgressDialog();

    }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
                    String src="http://"+ip+"/images/"+i+".jpg";
                    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    myBitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    if(myBitmap[i]!=null)
                        saveimagetoFile(myBitmap[i],i);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                return null;
            }
            return "successful";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            progress_dialog.hide();

        }
    }
```

and define a method for saving the images to sd card if you want:

```
void saveimagetoFile(Bitmap bmp,int num){
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            File file = new File(path, "PriceChecker/pc"+num+".jpg"); // the File to save to
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut); //save image to jpeg file
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```

but in my case the images where named 1.jpg , 2.jpg, 3.jpg ...etc
Hope this helps

**EDIT:**
method for showing progress dialog:

```
private void showProgressDialog(){
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        View promptView;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(OrderActivity_gridstyle.this);
        promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null);

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        progress_dialog=alertDialogBuilder.create();
        progress_dialog.show();}
```

the progress dialog I used is of shape: wheel, of course you can use different shape or type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/progress_time">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/prog_circle"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_wheel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Please Wait"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

which looks like this:
[image]

Comment: great this looks cool , and where do you prefer to update the progress bar ?

Comment: you can use the 2 mehtods: onPreExecute and onPostExecute to show and hide the dialog.

check the edit above :D

Comment: check this if you need to show progress in number or percentage:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043683/how-to-show-progress-bar-status-by-percentage

Answer (score 1):

If you have single download already up an running, what is the problem with chaining downloads for several images then? If you don't care about precise progress (atleast that is what I'm understanding here), you can simply do this by a for-loop.

Pseudo-Code:

```
String[] urlStack = {"http://www.myimage.com/1.jpg", "http://www.myimage.com/2.jpg", "http://www.myimage.com/3.jpg"};
for(int i = 0; i < urlStack.length; i++)
{
   yourAlreadyDoneDownloadProcedure(updateProgressCallback);
}
```

...
updateProgressCallback method of course gets called within your download procedure, once your download is done.
...

```
private void updateProgressFallback()
{
   progressBarText += 100 / urlStack.length;
}
```

This is just to demonstrate how you could / should approach this.

---

**Edit to your first comment:**

In this case you should use [FutureTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).

FutureTask objects can wait for completion, without any `while()...sleep`

e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < urlStack.length; i++)
{
   // fTask is an array of your download procedure objects

   // get() will wait until the Task is done, no manual sleep commands necessary
   fTask[i].get();

   // since we have a concatenation of downloads, we can update progress here
   progessBarText += 100 / urlStack.length;
}
```

---

**Edit to your second comment:**

You would have a Class that implements `Callable`, where all your magic happens:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<String>
{
    String url;

    public MyCallable(String s)
    {
        url = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception
    {
        // Download image here, you have the URL stored in `url`
        return "I'm done";
    }
}
```

Your FutureTask then runs that object:

```
MyCallable img1 = new MyCallable("http://www.myimage.com/1.jpg");    
MyCallable img2 = new MyCallable("http://www.myimage.com/2.jpg");    
FutureTask<String> fTask = new FutureTask<String>(img1);
fTask.get();
fTask = new FutureTask<String>(img2);
fTask.get();
```

Does this make it any clearer? The above code can be optimized a lot, this is just to get across what you need to know about `FutureTask`

Comment: and what about download the next image after completion of one , I do not want to set the for loop as it will launch so many async task

Comment: so how to make the  array of future task , I think we have single task and that is download the image , though downloading image is the process or task which is multiple. so should I made the future task of asynctask or where ?  I do not understand can you please explain more

Comment: I updated my answer, so you can understand the principle of FutureTask. After that, optimizing by putting all the Callables into an Array, Vector, etc. and then iterating through them would be highly recommended.