# Showing progress while downloading file

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I can download some file with retrofit library, its very simple. But i cannot find how to show progress of file download? In retrofit listener there are only two methods : onFailure and onResponse.

Comment: if file downloading is started when you click on click on button then you open a progress dialog on button click.In onsuccess and onerror dismiss progress.Be sure to put all this code in handler.

Comment: I need to show percent progress. For example, 18% , 25%, 56%, 90% ... Not only circle progress.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043683/how-to-show-progress-bar-status-by-percentage see this

Comment: I need to show progress, when downloading with RETROFIT library. In this link there no retrofit using

Comment: https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/05/downloading-file-using-retrofit.html

Comment: consider above example.

Comment: Also please check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348812/android-retrofit-onprogressupdate-for-showing-progress-notification

Comment: thanks, its what i searched

Answer (score 2):

Here is exactly what you are looking for:
https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/05/downloading-file-using-retrofit.html

You can use their way to calculate percent. Good luck!