# Static horizontal progress bar android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want a static progress bar in android. I will calculate the percentage at the time of activity load and it should show that throughout the activity.

Currently I have:-

```
<ProgressBar
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:layout_column="1" />
```

And I set the progress bar in the following way:-

```
ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progress.setProgress(term);
```

Its not showing anything and just the loading circle keeps rotating. I jsut want the following to show up. Its just a static value.

No it is not because I dont want an increasing percentage. I just want a static bar.

[image]

Comment: By default progress bar is spinning wheel, what you need is  style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show progress bar status by percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043683/how-to-show-progress-bar-status-by-percentage)

Comment: No its not a duplicate because I dont want an increasing percentage bar...its a static one.

Comment: @OlegBogdanov your solution worked but the the bar is shown completely full not like 90% filled or something

Comment: What is the value you are setting on it

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I am setting integer values like 97 for 97%

Comment: You don't see the text or you don't see the progress being set at 97? Can you try smth more visible, like 30,50,70?  Beware, Android progress bar not gonna show you text on it, that you have to implement yourself or use numerous alternatives

Answer (score 4):

You can use your percentage in FrameLayout and use them and set progress value in TextView.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="70 % complete"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```